# No quotes in the JSON read from the body of the request

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a question, maybe some of you have encountered this.

I have a REST service, which reads a JSON from the body of a POST request. I read the body like this:

```
IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream())
```

The problem is that the output of the `IOUtils.toString(...)` returns a JSON without the quotes surrounding the keywords.

Do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: don't use `IOUtils.toString` then

Comment: Are the quotes present in the actual request?

Comment: Please post some examples.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. It was because of the CLI through which I sent the curl requests. Thanks